# Creating second list with increment from other list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to create list2 from list1, but every member should have Z increment.

if Z=1 then: 
 [1,2,3] -> [2,3,4]

```
addZ(Z,[X | Xs],[Y | Ys]):-
Y is X+Z,
addZ(Z,Xs,Ys).
```

If I try `addZ(1,[1,2,3],X).`   I just get no as answer.

Comment: What happens when both lists are empty? You need to make that "base case" succeed. For the moment, there is nothing to tell Prolog to accept that case.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Thanks, I added ```addZ(_,[],[]).```, now it works but it doesn't stop without return.

Comment: The Prolog toplevel prints the first answer but is uncertain whether there may be another one, so you have to enter `;` to request that. However there is actually no second answer, so the Prolog toplevel prints _false_. This is as expected and not a problem. You can always demand to only output a single answer by wrapping the query into `once/1`: `once(addZ(1,[1,2,3],X))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the base case, as recommended by @DavidTonhofer, you can change the order of the first two arguments of the predicate to avoid **spurious choice points** (since Prolog apply first argument indexing to quickly narrow down applicable clauses):

```
addZ([], _, []).

addZ([X|Xs], Z, [Y|Ys]):-
    Y is X + Z,
    addZ(Xs, Z, Ys).
```

Example:

```
?- addZ([1,2,3], 1, Z).
Z = [2, 3, 4].

?-
```

Answer (score 1):

As always the most fun starts when you use CLP, like

```
:- use_module(library(clpz)).

addZ(_, [], []).
addZ(I, [X|Xs], [Y|Ys]) :- 
    Y #= I + X, 
    addZ(I, Xs, Ys).
```

And now you can do stuff like:

```
?- addZ(1, [1, 2, 3], C).
   C = [2,3,4].

?- addZ(1, [1, 2, X], [X, Y, 9]).
false.

?- addZ(4, [1, 2, X], [A, Y, 9]).
   A = 5, Y = 6, X = 5.

?- addZ(I, [1, 2, X], [5|Ys]).
   I = 4, Ys = [6,_A], clpz:(4+X#=_A).
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using [`maplist/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3) and library [`yall`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall):

```
addZ(Z, Xs, Ys):-
  maplist({Z}/[X, Y]>>(Y is X+Z), Xs, Ys).
```

Sample runs

```
?- addZ(1, [1,2,3], X).
X = [2, 3, 4].

?- addZ(5, [1,2,3], X).
X = [6, 7, 8].
```